# Get Permanent CWnd from HWnd

Tags: c++, mfc

We run into a problem with temporary handles.

As I read here: [What is the lifetime of a CWnd obtained from CWnd::FromHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504507/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-cwnd-obtained-from-cwndfromhandle)
`CWnd::FromHandle()` will create a temporary handle. Our plan was to store the handle for later use, but this won't work.

We also tried `CWnd::FromHandlePermanent()` but this somehow returns a null pointer .

And also `mpWnd->Attach(mhWnd);` threw an Access violation exception.

If possible we would like to store the `CWnd` rather than the `HWnd` and call `FromHandle()` everytime the `CWnd` is required.
Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: CWnd is not the same as a handle, it is just a Window-object-pointer; the "real" handle is hWnd as long as the window is open

Comment: You already know the solution. Why don't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You get only a permanent `CWnd` object if you **subclass** an existing window, or you create a `CWnd` with one of the `CWnd::Create` functions.

You should **not** use `Attach` in this situation. `Attach` is used by `SubclassWindow` and by the internal `Create` hooks. If you use `Attach` without subclassing, the window will not be removed from the handle map upon destruction.

So when you get an error with the `Attach` function then either the mpwnd object isn't valid, or the `CWnd` object is already subclassed.

Also, it doesn't make sense to me why you want to store a `CWnd` pointer. Use a **handle** and if needed use `FromHandle`. The drawback of subclassing windows always is: *that if your program later tries to subclass the window finally this fails, because it is already subclassed*.

Also your question doesn't give information **WHY** you want to do this.