# Can changing ImageList used by TVS_CHECKBOXES cause resource leak?

Tags: winapi, mfc, imagelist

**Win32:**

With a Tree Control created and the style changed to TVS_CHECKBOXES and then the ImageList for the TVSIL_STATE changed to a custom ImageList, do you need to delete the returned prior ImageList or is it a shared resource and should not be.

**MFC:**

Since there is an object hierarchy, in this case you don't know if the CImageList is replacing a one provided by the system or from one of the parent classes.  In that case what is the proper handling?  For ImageLists, can you `CImageList::Attach()`, `CTreeCtrl::SetImageList()`, `CImageList::Detach()` then `CTreeCtrl::OnDestroy()` go ahead and `CImageList *pil=CTreeCtrl::SetImageList(NULL, TVSIL_STATE)` and then `pil->DeleteImageList()`, but then what about the object, are we supposed to `delete pil` instead?  Or are we always required to setup a member variable that is the image list and just `CTreeCtrl::SetImageList()` to change it then `OnDestroy()` put back the old one or just set it to NULL?

Comment: [Beware of the leaked image list when using the TVS_CHECKBOXES style](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171128-00/?p=97475)

Comment: So in the Win32 case, that means YES.  What about the MFC case which uses CImageLists ?

Comment: MFC is a pretty thin wrapper so I'd guess it's the same but don't know for sure.

Comment: Check the Task Manager for GDI handles.

Comment: `CTreeCtrl::SetImageList()` returns a **temporary** object (via `CImageList::FromHandle()`) that does not own the handle it wraps. You have to `DeleteImageList()` to avoid the resource leak (see first comment), but never `delete` on the pointer returned by `SetImageList`. MFC automatically cleans up temporary objects during idle processing. [More about that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn003-mapping-of-windows-handles-to-objects?view=vs-2017).

Comment: @zett42 - Thanks, so if a base class is using a member variable, that handle may have already been deleted when the base class comes time to clean itself up?   Does MFC manage references to the handle in some way similar to COM or should base classes ensure they don't use member variables when they attach things like imagelists ?

Comment: Please drop a comment at my answer, if it still leaves things unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can changing ImageList used by TVS_CHECKBOXES cause resource leak?

Yes. From [Tree-View Control Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tree-view-control-window-styles):

> Destroying the tree-view control does not destroy the check box state
>   image list. You must destroy it explicitly. Get the handle to the
>   state image list by sending the tree-view control a [`TVM_GETIMAGELIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvm-getimagelist)
>   message. Then destroy the image list with [`ImageList_Destroy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_destroy).

Bonus "Old New Thing" link: [Beware of the leaked image list when using the TVS_CHECKBOXES style](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171128-00/?p=97475)

### Win32 Solution

We can take advantage of the fact that `TVM_SETIMAGELIST` (wrapped by `TreeView_SetImageList()`) returns the handle to the previous image list.

```
HIMAGELIST hNewImageList = ImageList_Create(/* insert arguments */);
HIMAGELIST hOldImageList = TreeView_SetImageList( hwndTreeView, hNewImageList, TVSIL_STATE );
if( hOldImageList )  // a good habit, to check if handle is not NULL
{
    ImageList_Destroy( hOldImageList );
    hOldImageList = NULL;
}
```

After the tree control has been destroyed, you also have to `ImageList_Destroy` the new image list.

### MFC Solution

MFC is not that much different, i. e. it doesn't automatically clean up the image list created by the `TVS_CHECKBOXES` style.

Create a member variable `CImageList m_newImageList;` in the declaration of the class that hosts the tree control (e. g. a `CDialog` derived class). This makes sure that the new image lists lifetime does not end before that of the tree control window and automatically destroys the image list through its destructor.

```
m_newImageList.Create(/* insert arguments */);
CImageList* pOldImageList = m_treeCtrl.SetImageList( &m_newImageList, TVSIL_STATE );
if( pOldImageList )
{
    pOldImageList->DeleteImageList();
    pOldImageList = nullptr;
}
```

`CTreeCtrl::SetImageList()` returns a pointer to a temporary object (via `CImageList::FromHandle()`) that does not own the handle it wraps. You have to `DeleteImageList()` to avoid the resource leak, but never `delete` on the pointer returned by `SetImageList`. MFC automatically cleans up temporary objects during idle processing (in `CWinApp::OnIdle()`).

Further reading:

- [TN003: Mapping of Windows Handles to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn003-mapping-of-windows-handles-to-objects?view=vs-2017).
- [What is the lifetime of a CWnd obtained from CWnd::FromHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504507/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-cwnd-obtained-from-cwndfromhandle)
  (replace `CWnd` by `CImageList`, the `FromHandle()` methods of MFC classes all work in the same way).

Comment: good info, just one question remains when using a MFC and member variable.  say something extends that base class and puts in its own image list using process above.  the member variable handle is now invalid in the base? or does it somehow sync that?

Comment: @user3161924 This scenario works without further ado. The base class's member variable is kept in sync through the MFC handle map. When you call `CImageList::Create()`, MFC stores the `HIMAGELIST` and a pointer to `CImageList` in the "permanent" handle map. When you call `SetImageList()`, you will effectively get a pointer to the `CImageList` member variable of the base class.  When you call `pOldImageList->DeleteImageList()` as in my code sample, you will delete the image list through the base class's member.